# HTML & CSS Floating jquery menu

Tags: html, css

I have websie and a left menu on it.

I wish to make this menu to be the same as `position:fixed;` in CSS but when resizing website it would still be on the same place and when I scroll to a spceific div, we say "contact" it makes contact `<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>` with bigger font in the menu ul.

Do someone know a plugin for it or any tutorial on ho to make it?

Comment: what did you try ? which problems did you had ? it would be easier to help you if you could post some code or a jsfiddle

Comment: Like Frederik said, please try to attempt before you ask the question.  People won't respond to questions that shows the asker didn't do any research. What did you try? What didn't work? Please edit your attempts into your original question.

Comment: I wanted to try, but I don't know where to begin with in that case, I made the CSS of the menu, the respond to `:hover` and named all `div`s IDs as supposed. But now comes the main question how to make it like i described.

Answer (score 0):

When you hover it, make the css styling with bigger font. Ex :

```
    a:hover{
        font-size:20px;
        }
```

for links.
And for plugins ,

http://www.jquery4u.com/menus/floating-message-plugins/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is not the answer to my question